# Cleanly force Log4j RollingFileAppender to roll shortly after midnight?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

The normal behavior of the Log4j RollingFileAppender is to roll when the first log message occurs on a different day, but some feel warm and fuzzy with empty logfiles for each date, even if nothing occurred.  Is there a way to force it to roll after midnight without writing dummy messages to the log?

Comment: My guess is that this isn't the default behavior because this would require some kind of timer thread to be running in the background which would require your application to be constantly running.  This isn't a limit imposed by log4j.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked at this code very closely - the simple answer is 'no'.  The rollover is triggered as part of the doAppend() flow on the Appender - the only way to trigger it is to log something.

You could fake this with cron: just have a cron script touch the file for tomorrow at like 11:58.  That will get you the empty logfile behavior you're looking for.

Here's the code that implements the rollover function:

```
void rollOver() throws IOException {

    /* Compute filename, but only if datePattern is specified */
    if (datePattern == null) {
      errorHandler.error("Missing DatePattern option in rollOver().");
      return;
    }

    String datedFilename = fileName+sdf.format(now);
    // It is too early to roll over because we are still within the
    // bounds of the current interval. Rollover will occur once the
    // next interval is reached.
    if (scheduledFilename.equals(datedFilename)) {
      return;
    }

    // close current file, and rename it to datedFilename
    this.closeFile();

    File target  = new File(scheduledFilename);
    if (target.exists()) {
      target.delete();
    }

    File file = new File(fileName);
    boolean result = file.renameTo(target);
    if(result) {
      LogLog.debug(fileName +" -> "+ scheduledFilename);
    } else {
      LogLog.error("Failed to rename ["+fileName+"] to ["+scheduledFilename+"].");
    }

    try {
      // This will also close the file. This is OK since multiple
      // close operations are safe.
      this.setFile(fileName, false, this.bufferedIO, this.bufferSize);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
      errorHandler.error("setFile("+fileName+", false) call failed.");
    }
    scheduledFilename = datedFilename;
  }
```

Comment: It's also possible to call RollingFileAppender.rollOver if you can get access to the appender.

Comment: Calling rollover() when the log doesn't exist won't get the asker what they wanted: an empty logfile for the right date and time.